What should we store in the session when using session-based authentication?
I'm learning how to use session-based authentication for my web app, but I'm not sure what kind of data should be stored in the session.
What information do I need to keep in the session after a user logs in?
Should I store things like the user's password or just their ID?

What information do you need?  For example, you mention storing the user's password.  Why do you need that?  Not to mention that you shouldn't have the user's original plain-text password in the first place, only a hashed version.  What do you need that value for after the user has been authenticated?  If you don't need it then there's no reason to store it in session.

Firstly, you should never store passwords in plaintext; even in the DB they're stored as hashes, not as a plaintext. Technically, you could store the hashes in sessions, but there's typically no good reason to do that.
The simplest approach is to store the userID in the session (and keep SessionID in a cookie). This way, each time the user makes a request, your server-side code can retrieve the userID from the session and use it to get any other relevant user data from the database.
You can also store other data, e.g. comma-delimited permissions, in sessions, however note that in this case using JWT may be a better option.
Also, remember that it's usually best to use the authentication methods provided by the framework you're using (ASP.NET Core, Django, etc.), rather than trying to implement your own.

Since session data is stored on the server and not accessible on the client, there are a lot of options on how to organize the session data, but I have never seen the password being stored in the session.  It would work to store the username and password, but then you need to do the authentication step on every request to grab the userID, which is extra work.  Storing the primary key of the logged in user makes a lot more sense.
Also in general, I try not to store the password in extra places if I can, even in places that are in theory secure.  I personally don't even store the passwords inside of systems, instead relying on a hash that can be computed from the password to verify the correct password was used during authentication without having to actually store it.
I really had this drilled into my head when at a Microsoft coding event the presenter was showing example code for session authentication and encouraged users to create accounts and login.  Then he tried the email and passwords they signed up with against gmail to see if he could login to their email and he was successful.
Either UserID or SessionID is going to make the most sense, I have also seen permission bit-strings.  SessionID can be nice because many times admin users can login as various roles including impersonating other users to do the sorts of things admin users need to do, though you could also build this sort of functionality into the session directly as well.
I hope this helps!
